# Check if email exists in database using phalcon

Tags: php, sql, database, forms, phalcon

I have the following code:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function registerAction()
    {


        $user = new Users();

        // Store and check for errors
        $success = $user->save(
            $this->request->getPost(),
            [
                "name",
                "email",
            ]
        );

        // Instantiate the Query
        $query = new Query(
            'SELECT email FROM users',
            $this->getDI()
        );

        // Execute the query returning a result if any
        $users = $query->execute();


        if($user==$users)
        {
            echo "Email already exists";
        }

        else if ($success)
        {
            echo "Thanks for registering!";
        } else
            {
            echo "Sorry, the following problems were generated: ";

            $messages = $user->getMessages();

            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
            }
        }


        $this->view->disable();
    }
}
```

what i am trying to do is to check if the given email is already registerd in the database.

I tried to do that with this part of the code

```
// Instantiate the Query
        $query = new Query(
            'SELECT email FROM users',
            $this->getDI()
        );

        // Execute the query returning a result if any
        $users = $query->execute();


        if($user==$users)
        {
            echo "Email already exists";
        }
```

It doesn't seems to work and I am getting the following error

"**Exception: Can't obtain model's source from models list: 'Users', when preparing: SELECT email FROM users**"

My models list code is the following

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $email;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I suppose to check if the given email is already added to the database and then "echo" the appropriate message .

Thanks in advance for your time

**Final worked Code**

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;


class SignupController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'users';
    }




    public function registerAction()
    {

        $user = new Users();

        $email = $this->request->getPost('email', 'string', '');
        $result = users::findFirst(
            [
                'conditions' => 'email = :email:',
                'bind' => [
                    'email' => $email,
                ]
            ]
        );

        if (false !== $result) {
            echo 'The email exists in the database';
        } else {

            // Store and check for errors
            $success = $user->save(
                $this->request->getPost(),
                [
                    "name",
                    "email",
                ]
            );

            if ($success) {
                echo "Thanks for registering!";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, the following problems were generated: ";

                $messages = $user->getMessages();

                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
                }
            }


            $this->view->disable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with phalcon but you do not appear to have a `WHERE` clause on your query. `SELECT email FROM users` will select all emails. You want to look for a specific one -- something like `SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email` and then bind the value of the email you're looking for.

Comment: @AlexHowansky that looks as a good comment , i tried it but now give me "Exception: Scanner: Unknown opcode 58" .

PS: also not familiar with phalcon , i'm trying to learn it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your error you need to tell the model what table it maps to:

```
public function getSource()
{
    return 'users';
}
```

A bit of an easier approach is using `findFirst` on the model like this:

```
$email  = $this->request->getPost('email', 'string', '');
$result = Users::findFirst(
    [
        'conditions' => 'email = :email:',
        'bind'       => [
            'email' => $email,
        ]
    ]
);

if (false !== $result) {
    echo 'The email exists in the database';
}
```

What the above code does:
- Get the `email` from the posted data. Sanitize it as string. If it has not been posted, return an empty string
- Search the `Users` model for an email that exists in any record for the `email` field.
- If nothing has been returned continue, if a match has been found echo the result out.

Comment: It is because you have the logic wrong there. When someone registers you first have to check whether their email exists and output the correct message. If it does not exist THEN you need to save the record and the email. You just need to change the steps.